# autoloading test classes in clojure ?

Tags: testing, clojure

I have a test suite in Clojure using core.test that I run by starting by server, starting emacs, connecting to my REPL using Cider, and evaluating

```
(run-tests 'im.user-test
           'im.organization-test
           'im.group-test
           'im.content-test
           'im.orders-test
           'im.db-test
           'im.collection-test)
```

The problem is to run the above, I need to first open up each one of those files and evaluate them in the REPL before the above will work because the repl doesn't know about these classes. If I try to require the test without going to the file and evaluating it, I get the error "Could not locate im/orders_test__init.class or im/orders_test.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name."

Each of my test files is in /test and for example my main test file looks like.

```
(ns im.core-test
  (:import datomic.Util)
  (:require
   [im.db :as db]
   [im.models.user :as user]
   [clojure.java.io :as io]
   [clojure.test :refer :all]
   [clj-http.client :as client]
   [datomic.api :as d]
   [environ.core :refer [env]]))

   (defn reload-db [test-fn]
     (with-redefs [db/uri db/testuri]
       (db/reload-db)
       (with-redefs [db/conn (d/connect db/testuri)]
         (test-fn))))

 (comment
    (run-tests 'im.user-test
               'im.organization-test
               'im.group-test
               'im.content-test
               'im.orders-test
               'im.db-test
               'im.collection-test))
```

and for example a test file would look like this

```
;; app_root/test/orders_test.clj
(ns im.orders-test
  (:require
   [im.models.order :as o]
   [im.db :as db]
   [clojure.test :refer :all]))
```

So, is there a way to automatically load all the test classes, or am I going about this entirely wrong in general?

Comment: Simply running [`run-all-tests`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/run-all-tests) doesn’t work for you?

Comment: Ahhh amazing! Thanks, I do 
(run-all-tests #"im.*") to isolate to my "im." classes. Thanks!

Comment: you might also like https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh

Comment: @TimothyPratley using this plugin I run into same issue of not being able to load test classes.

Comment: I don't follow, where are the classes? I only see namespaces. All tests in the "src" and "test" directories get picked up by test-refresh automatically, is there something specific about your tests that is preventing this?

Comment: Sorry... I mean namespaces (skipped comp sci). Perhaps there is something about my tests preventing it, I'll try on a clean project to debug.